# Turkish small cap dotted 'i' in footnote

Tags: xetex, luatex, polyglossia, small-caps, turkish

LuaLaTeX renders Turkish small cap dotted 'i'  correctly in the main body of the text, but not in footnotes. Are there any solutions?

Here is a **MWE:**

```
%!TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{turkish}
\usepackage[semibold]{libertine}


\begin{document}
    In Turkish,  `\textsc{ı}' and `\textsc{i}' are different letters.\footnote{In Turkish,  `\textsc{ı}' and `\textsc{i}' are different letters.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: good question, it works with `\footnotesize` text in the main body so it's the footnote command not the font that is the problem, xelatex fails the same way though

Comment: `\footnote` triggers `\ignorespaces`. If you put `\ignorespaces` in the normal text, it loses the dot too. But if you remove the `\ignorespaces` from `\footnote` it doesnt wotk :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Load the font with the `Language=Turkish` option:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{turkish}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}[
  Language=Turkish,
  BoldFont=* Semibold,
  BoldItalicFont=* Semibold Italic,
]

\setlength{\textheight}{2cm}

\begin{document}

In Turkish,  `\textsc{ı}' and `\textsc{i}' are different
letters.\footnote{In Turkish,  `\textsc{ı}' and `\textsc{i}'
are different letters.}

\textbf{Abc} \textbf{\textit{Abc}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I don't think it should be be needed but you can re-assert turkish in the footnote:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{turkish}
\usepackage[semibold]{libertine}


\begin{document}

 In Turkish,  `\textsc{ı}' and `\textsc{i}' are different letters.

{\footnotesize In Turkish,  `\textsc{ı}' and `\textsc{i}' are different letters.}


x\footnote{\textturkish{In Turkish,  `\textsc{ı}' and `\textsc{i}' are different letters.}}


\end{document}
```

---

I think the root cause is `\normalfont`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{turkish}
\usepackage[semibold]{libertine}


\begin{document}

 In Turkish,  `\textsc{ı}' and `\textsc{i}' are different letters.

{\footnotesize In Turkish,  `\textsc{ı}' and `\textsc{i}' are different letters.}


{\normalfont\footnotesize In Turkish,  `\textsc{ı}' and `\textsc{i}' are different letters.}


x\footnote{In Turkish,  `\textsc{ı}' and `\textsc{i}' are different letters.}

x\footnote{\textturkish{In Turkish,  `\textsc{ı}' and `\textsc{i}' are different letters.}}


\end{document}
```

`\normalfont` (which is used to reset the font in footnotes, headings and other places) ends up selecting `LinLibertine(0)` whereas for Turkish it should be
`LinLibertine(9)`  I'm not sure if that's the responsibility of `fontspec` or `polyglossia`  but I'll ask...

Answer (score 6):

babel has a new interface to setup language dependant fonts. It seems to handle this correctly:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[english,turkish]{babel}
\babelfont[english]{rm}[Language=Default]{Linux Libertine O}
\babelfont[turkish]{rm}[Language=Turkish]{Linux Libertine O}


\begin{document}
    In Turkish,  `\textsc{ı}' and `\textsc{i}' are different letters.%
    \footnote{In Turkish,  `\textsc{ı}' and `\textsc{i}' are different letters.}

    \selectlanguage{english}
    In english,  `\textsc{ı}' and `\textsc{i}' %
    \footnote{In english,  `\textsc{ı}' and `\textsc{i}'}


\end{document}
```

[image]

But you won't be able to use the libertine package. The babel document says explicitly that you must setup the fonts with `\babelfont` and not `\setXXfont`.

Comment: And even simpler: `\babelfont{rm}{Linux Libertine O}`. That's all — `babel`defines and switches the fonts for you (which is the main point of `\babelfont`).